# Maximum update depth exceeded when updating react state on componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What react life cycle should I use to update the local state that I have on my component with information that comes from an axios GET method?

So far I tried `componentDidMount` but the axios is not completed there, so the prop is empty `[]`.
I also tried `componentDidUpdate`. Surprisingly, the axios GET is completed here, but when I try to update the state, I get the warning for Maximum update depth exceeded.

A sample of my code follows:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
   const {item} = this.props; // this is coming from axios

   this.setState({
        ...
   });
}
```

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` runs every time your component updates (state or props changes). If you call `setState` unconditionally in `componentDidUpdate`, then you've got yourself a problem.

Comment: can you share the parent component and the rest of this component's code? would be easier to help you

Comment: Why not just `setState` inside axios's `.then()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check item equality value before setState function as below:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   const {item} = this.props; // this is coming from axios

   if(prevProps.item === item) return;

   this.setState({
        ...
   });
}
```

Comment: That if statement actually helped me! this is what I was missing all along! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As they say in the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate :

```
You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that 
it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or you’ll 
cause an infinite loop
```

You are calling setState all the time which causes an infinite loop.